# How to retrieve the highest value on same data ID

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

For my monitoring tool (Centreon), I need to create a script that will send me every day a report with my hosts / services that have been acknowledged for X days.

For this I need to get information in several tables which I can do with the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT     services.host_id,
                        hosts.name,
                        services.service_id,
                        services.description,
                        comments.author,
                        comments.DATA,from_unixtime(comments.entry_time), 
                        comments.comment_id
FROM  services,
        hosts,
        comments 
WHERE services.host_id=hosts.host_id 
        AND hosts.host_id=comments.host_id 
        AND services.acknowledged='1' 
        AND services.enabled='1' 
        AND comments.DATA NOT LIKE '%downtime%'
```

[MySQL query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P8pw.png)

What I'll need is to have as result only the highest comment_id per service_id

Is there a way to do this directly in a query or do I have to import my entire result into my python script and process the data afterwards?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *only the highest comment_id per service_id* What about another columns? Any? From the same row? something else? And specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: This is something of a FAQ, and hence easily solved with a quick search. Nevertheless, if you're still struggling, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Sort Inside of Group By Results**

You can "[GROUP By](https://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/how-to-use-group-by-having-and-order-by-sql-clauses/)" the results by `service_id` and use **"MAX()"** (Aggregate Function, you can also use Min() ) to have the highest comment in the grouped result. Try the following query:

```
SELECT services.host_id,
                hosts.name,
                services.service_id,
                services.description,
                comments.author,
                comments.DATA,
                from_unixtime(comments.entry_time), 
                max(comments.comment_id)
FROM services,
     hosts,
     comments 
WHERE services.host_id=hosts.host_id 
  AND hosts.host_id=comments.host_id 
  AND services.acknowledged='1' 
  AND services.enabled='1' 
  AND comments.DATA NOT LIKE '%downtime%'
GROUP By services.service_id
;
```

Comment: Hello Soroosh, 

First thanks you for your answer.

That's almost right! But the problem is that when you put the ORDER command at the end, the data field doesn't correspond to the comment_id anymore.

I have try to put the ORDER before the GROUP BY but it's not working.

Comment: Try updated answer, It was actually my first answer, but I don't know why I thought It was wrong and changed it to order by.

Comment: I have try and unfortunaltely is not working. I have test a lot of query but i dont know why if i order or use MAX the comment don't match with the service_id

Comment: I think you should remove DISTINCT from start of the Query.

Comment: Oh yes , if i remove DISTINCT and i add MAX is working . Thanks a lot !